# Where to set the name of the app when OTA updating enterprise app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-enterprise

We are trying to update one of our enterprise apps we get this message:

App update
The server "my.server.com" is about to update the app "Unknown".

We would like to change this to "My App"
I've tried changing the "Bundle creator OS Type code" in the info.plist to no luck.

Comment: Can you add the `manifest.plist` xml to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it! It was either the "CFBundleDisplayName" or "CFBundleName" in my xxxx-info.plist file. Both had disappeared...